# Can't change git configuration within a docker container run in WSL

Tags: git, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

From within my docker container, `git config` is unable to edit the .gitconfig file:

```
root@fc7684ffdb39:~/beta_install $ git config --global user.name "Mona Lisa"
error: could not write config file /root/.gitconfig: Device or resource busy
```

But, I can edit it otherwise:

```
root@f60a0bc9939f:~/beta_install $ echo "#blahblah" >> /root/.gitconfig
root@f60a0bc9939f:~/beta_install $ cat /root/.gitconfig'
...
...
#blahblah
```

I can edit the .gitconfig from the WSL installation using git:

```
user@comp$ git config --global user.name "global from wsl"
user@comp$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
        ...
        name = global from wsl
```

My compose.yaml:

```
services:
  dev:
      container_name: dev_env
      build:
        context: .
        ssh:
          - default
        args:
          DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
      volumes:
        -  ./dock_dev_src:/root/beta_devel/src/
        -  /.ssh:/root/.ssh
        -  $HOME/.gitconfig:/root/.gitconfig
      environment:
          DISPLAY: "192.168.16.1:0.0"
      image: dev1
      stdin_open: true # docker run -i
      tty: true        # docker run -t
```

setting permissions at 777 and chowning it don't seem to have an effect:

```
root@f60a0bc9939f:~/beta_install $ chmod 777 /root/.gitconfig
root@f60a0bc9939f:~/beta_install $ chown root:root /root/.gitconfig
root@f60a0bc9939f:~/beta_install $ git config --global user.name "globalfromcontainer"
error: could not write config file /root/.gitconfig: Device or resource busy
```

I would like to be able to modify this file from within a running container. How can I do it?

Comment: note that your are _mounting_ your local `.gitconfig` file within the container. Sucesfully editing the file from within the container will mean that you modified you local file (e.g: `user.name` will be `"Mona Lisa"` on your computer too. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes. ten_more_characters.